# Parsing String from XML to C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, parsing

I have written the following code in XML and I want to parse it to C# and show it in a ListBox.

This is the code from the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root (Persoane*)>
  <!ELEMENT Persoane (nume)>
  <!ELEMENT IsMale (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT Varsta (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT PersoanaPlacuta (#PCDATA)>
 ]>
<root>
  <Persoane nume ="Bob">
    <IsMale>true</IsMale>
    <Varsta>30</Varsta>
    <PersoanaPlacuta>"Iulia"</PersoanaPlacuta>
  </Persoane>
</root>
```

and this is the code in C#:

```
private void LoadPersoane()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XDocument persoanaPlacuta = new XDocument();

        doc.Load("Baza_de_cunostinte.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement) 
        {
            string nume = node.Attributes[0].Value;
            int varsta = int.Parse(node["Varsta"].InnerText);
            bool isMale = bool.Parse(node["IsMale"].InnerText);
            persoanaPlacuta = XDocument.Parse(node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText);

            listBox.Items.Add(new Persoane(nume, varsta, isMale, persoanaPlacuta));
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine, except the field "PersoanaPlacuta". I don't know how to parse it to C#... I tried, but with no luck...

Comment: no luck how?  What's it doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the XDocument.Parse().  Not sure why you added it, but it only causes problems.

Comment: `node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText` is the string `"Iulia"` why are you attempting to generate an XDocument from it?

Comment: Why are you mixing the old `XmlDocument` DOM with the new `XDocument` DOM?  You should really only use one and honestly `XDocument` is more feature rich.

Comment: Yes, node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText is the string "Iulia" I want to generate...

Comment: I've deleted XDocument.Parse(). But I don't know what to use instead of it. That was just a try to get the result desired, "Iulia"

Comment: `node["PersoanaPlacuta"].InnerText.Replace("\"", "")`?

Comment: thank you, @ChristianGollhardt . It worked :)